# Perl cannot find MAIL::IMAPClient

Tags: perl

i'm trying to execute a simple login to gmail usign perl
i have installed perl in C:\Dwimperl
So when i try this sample code:

```
#!C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::IMAPClient;

# Connect to IMAP server
my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
    User     => 'email@gmail.com',
    Password => 'password',
    Port     => 993,
    Ssl      => 1,
) or die "Cannot connect through IMAPClient: $!";

# List folders on remote server (see if all is ok)
if ( $client->IsAuthenticated() ) {
    print "Folders:\n";
    print "- ", $_, "\n" for @{ $client->folders() };
}

# Say so long
$client->logout();
```

I have the following error:

```
Can't locate Mail/IMAPClient.pm in @INC <@INC contains: c:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread c:/dwimperl/perl/site/lib c:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib c:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .> at logingmail.pl line4
```

i copied the file file IMAPClient.pm in all folders mentioned in the error message.
And i still have the same message.
Any hel^please, thank you

Comment: You should install it using the supplied install script, or with cpan, or another perl module manager. If you are going to install modules by hand (which I would not recommend!), IMAPClient.pm needs to be in a directory called Mail. But don't install modules by hand.

Comment: Ok i just put the file IMAPCLient.pn in a folder Mail and now it says Cannot connect through IMPACLient: Bad file descriptor at Test.pl line 7

Comment: Great! That means perl has found IMAPClient. Troubleshooting: https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient#Errors

Comment: [How to install CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

Answer (score 1):

> i copied the file file IMAPClient.pm in all folders mentioned in the
>   error message. And i still have the same message.

In you working directory you should create 'Mail' dir and put the file IMAPClient.pm in it.

Comment: edem is right. The module is Mail::IMAPClient.pm so Perl is looking through the directories in @INC for a Mail directory that contains IMAPClient.pm.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't locate Mail/IMAPClient.pm

Do you use ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl? You must install all modules into your Perl system in order to be able to use them. From the command line try:

```
C> cpan install Mail::IMAPClient
```

Active Perl uses the [Perl Package Manager](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html) to download packages. You might find that easier to use. Try installing Mail-IMAPClient.

`@INC` usually includes the current directory, so you can put the package there, but you must create the appropriate directory structure. `Mail::IMAPClient` package means that you must have a file called `Mail/IMAPClient.pm` in the current directory. That is, the file `IMAPClient.pm` must be in a `Mail` directory under the current directory.